# Capturar valores seguidos de um textarea na mesma função

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo um console com HTML5 + Vue para agilizar alguns comandos simples.

O comando inserido vem através de uma textarea com `v-model="cmd" v-on:keyup.enter="consoleMode()"`.

Estou usando o else if mesmo, visto que só preciso de umas 4 funções.

```
consoleMode: function(cmd){
  this.cmdHistory.push({command: this.cmd})
  if(this.cmd == 'cls\n'){
    this.cmdHistory = [{command: 'início'}]
  } else if(this.cmd == 'add client\n'){
    this.cmdQuest = 'Qual o nome do cliente?'
    //ler a primeira resposta e fazer outras perguntas
  } else if(this.cmd == 'exit\n'){
    this.cmdQuest = ''
  }
  this.cmd = ''
}
```

Eu travei na primeira pergunta, pois não tenho ideia como faço para capturar uns valores no estilo `scanf` no C com essa textarea.

Basicamente, preciso que nesse if ele capture 4 valores seguidos (um por um, sempre limpando a textarea) e jogue em um objeto `newClient`, alternando o valor de `this.cmdQuest` para cada nova linha("Qual o nome?", "Qual o CPF?", etc.).

Se houver algum plugin para ajudar nisso, seria legal.

**EDIT1:** o `this.cmdHistory` é um array com objetos tipo {command: 'meu último comando'}
http://prntscr.com/g406fv